# NSMutableArray accessor returning NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *childrenArray;
```

Now i initialize it like this:

```
self.childrenArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:children];
```

children is also nsmutable above,

Now when i was removing an object from children array i got this error:

```
[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent
```

I instantly understood that my remove was being called on NSArray, so my query is why my accessor is returning NSArray as it is supposed to return NSMutableArray.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a `copy` @property literally sends `copy` to the object being set.  A mutable collection responds to `copy` by creating an immutable copy.   Mutable copying is rife with edge cases (of which many have been covered in other SO questions).

Secondly, you really *really* don't want properties providing access to mutable state within an object.  And you probably don't want to vend mutable collection classes.

---

Blunt:

Sending `copy` to a mutable collection returns an immutable copy.  A `copy` property will not preserve mutability.

Manually implementing the setter/getter to set/return mutable instances is probably wrong.

---

Think of it this way:

You have a class named "Person" that has an property named "firstName".   If that property were mutable, someone might say:

```
 [[aPerson firstName] setString:@"Joe"];
```

I.e. would you want someone to be able to change your first name without any kind of a notification that they did so?  Probably not.  But that is *exactly* what you are allowing by exposing the state of an object in a mutable container.

Comment: Hi thanks,I am sorry i couldn't get you, can u explain it in bit more simpler, If its problem with copy then should i use retain ?

Comment: Hi after reading your answer again and again, What i understood is: First I am not manualy implemented setter and getter, synthesize is doing everything, so it means when i am initializing my mutable array with setter then it calls copy and copy doesn't preserve mutability so accessor returns immutable. Secondly, so what i need is to initialize on member directly instead of self.member like this childrenArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:children] retain]; (Correct me if i m still wrong). Thanks

Comment: I also think that i should be using retain semantic instead of copy since copy is returning immutable. Thanks.

Comment: `retain` will work, yes, but -- overall -- you don't want to expose mutable collections from *inside* an instance to the outside world.  It breaks encapsulation.